# Azure APIM Fails to Create API from Function App

Tags: azure-api-management

When I try to create an API in APIM by using `Create from Function App`, I fill out the fields and click `Create`. The operation provides the wait dots and comes back in five seconds and says

> Could not create an API. Please try again later.

I can create a blank API...but not one from an existing Function App. I have tried multiple combinations, No products, all products, no version, version..etc. No luck.

Thoughts?

---

[image]

---

**Notes**

- The function in question is an HTTP Trigger.
- The function works locally on my development box and in Azure.
- APIM Tier is Developer
- On that Function app, during Publish in Visual Studio I have reported that attempting to manage application settings before a publish fails and in trying to add a new one causes Visual Studio to unexpectedly close.  [Manage Application Settings on Publish](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/430313/manage-application-settings-on-publish.html) Related, don't know.

Comment: Did you see any related activity logs in Portal?

Comment: On the APIM blade, when I scroll down to `Logs` and the blade displays, it displays with no logs. Is there a different location to view?

Comment: You should select activity logs in APIM blade and filter by the issue time period. Could you share the service name?

Comment: Is there anything in browser console?

Answer (score 23):

Just a Ctrl + F5 solved the problem for me. Try it!  ;)

Comment: Didn't expect this to actually work, but lo and behold it surprisingly did. This also worked for me with a different error than the OP in case someone comes here like I did searching for a solution. The error in my case was related to not being able to get the config data from my function app.

Comment: Also worked for me when I had this issue too!

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue because I used `Linux (Preview)` instead of Windows.  When I blew away the Function App and recreated a new one with Windows, my API Manager was able to create an API off it.

Comment: We are running Windows but still experience the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: This seems to still be an issue with Linux based function apps.

Comment: Is it possible to setup Linux function apps with API Management using ARM templates?

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduce the same scenario. It is working for me. May I know, below details,
01.Hope you have tested your function and it is working fine.
02.What is the type of the function ? Hope that is "Http trigger" ?
03.What is you APIM tier ? (eg : development, basic etc.)

Comment: Hope you have follwed below link. Kindly check the note, You can import only Functions that are based off HTTP trigger and have the authorization level setting set to Anonymous or Function.                 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-function-app-as-api

Answer (score 1):

At this time the solution for me was to use Microsoft Edge instead of Chrome.

It seems Microsoft Azure portal is not working properly in Chrome and I noticed issues in several places. Parts of pages are not rendered at all and sometimes even errors like this pop up just because of the browser.

Comment: I've seen similar with other Azure tools, where one would have to switch browsers. That is why one never deletes the copy of `Mozilla` they have.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.
The fix was both simple and unexpected.

When importing the function app, simply enter "/" in the API URL Suffix field.
For me this changed the BaseURL field value.  Originally it was just the host, ie `http://hostname/`.  It then appended the endpoint the hostname, `http://hostname/endpoint`
This is done on the "Create Function from App" modal.

[image: Click for screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to publish my Azure Functions application with several HTTP triggered functions through API Management running on Consumption plan. The plan did not have anything to do with the problem though.

What I did not realize was that my function app was not working properly when browsing it from the Azure portal. I had some configuration errors that prevented the app to work properly. When I resolved those, I succeeded to publish the application through APIM.

So, check that your application is working properly by browsing to it if you run into the problem described in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the function did not actually work.

The `Browse` button that redirects to the page with the light bulb and the text `Your function app version X is up and running` did show, but the function still didn't work.

The function error had to be fixed before when importing to the APIM was done.

Answer (score 1):

I had temporarily suspended (or stopped) my Function App. Restarting it resolved the problem.

I hope Azure could improve the error message, at least from UX perspective.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue after deploying our azure functions. We were using the azure plugin to deploy the functions and it turns out that we were overwriting the "AzureWebJobsStorage": "" key to nothing as set in our local.setting.json

To solve the problem just delete the azure function and redeploy the azure function and azure will automatically fill in the value for "AzureWebJobsStorage" after the storage has been created.

In the future just make sure that during deployment the key value pairs are not overwritten.