# Could not create an API using Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I'm trying to create an API using an existing Azure Function App.

Function App Properties:

- OS: Linux
- Hosting Plan: Consumption Plan
- Runtime Stack: Python

Here is the error:

[image: Error image]

Comment: [Someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54226135/azure-apim-fails-to-create-api-from-function-app) throw away the function and recreate a new one on windows. Then apim could create with it.

Comment: yeah, I have seen that. They used the Windows OS instead of Linux. In my case, I'm trying to create python function on Linux OS.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Function App import is not yet supported, but coming real soon.